# Sharepoint Online Guest link requires login to view page

Tags: office365, sharepoint-online

As per this Office article : https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Manage-external-sharing-for-your-SharePoint-Online-environment-c8a462eb-0723-4b0b-8d0a-70feafe4be85

"What are the external sharing features of SharePoint Online? The ability to share documents with guest users.    Guest users, also called anonymous users, don’t need aMicrosoft account or work or school account to access documents. They access the document via a guest link that you or your employees give to them."

I created guest link and shared this link to a web page to couple users and all of them are getting office 365 login page : https://login.microsoftonline.com. So if they do not require login then why are they getting office 365 login page ?

Is it possible to share a web page anonymously without login on sharepoint online ?

Answer (score 0):

When you click on Share button to share a site or a document, type Everyone which will lead to share an item with everyone with no need to login. You need to turn on external sharing feature on the tenant as well. also, make sure to un check Require sign-in check box.

[image]

Here is how to enable external user sharing from SP Admin Console:

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi thanks for your response, is your approach different from sharing a guest link ? or do I need to share it with everyone before I can send guest link to few users in order to avoid login ?

Comment: Getting a shared link is to created just a link but it doesn't guarantee that whoever receive the link is able to view it unless you add them under invite tab.

Comment: Hi I checked "Sharing outside your company" is set to : Allow both external users who accept sharing invitations and anonymous guest links also I put : Everyone under invite people while sharing document and unchecked Require sign-in checkbox and then asked users to click on guest link and it is still taking them to microsoft login page. Do you have guest link to share with me so that I can check how is it working for you ?

Comment: based on this post : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/e8d0f110-bcf5-45b4-8e8c-5d127df711fd/sharepoint-online-guest-link-requires-login-to-view-page?forum=sharepointdevelopment I got to know that guest links require login for web/HTML pages while it is not needed for other type of documents (e.g. PDF, Word, ..), for these type of documents guest link is enough to share with everyone anonymously and you do not need to put everyone in Invite People tab. Does anyone know if it is possible to share web /HTML page using guest link without requiring login ?